# How to export API JSON data to CSV file with Python

Tags: python, json, export-to-csv

I faced with a problem. I've got some data in JSON format with API.

It looks like that:

Example:

```
{"ID":"938","ENTITY_ID":"CRM_DEAL","FIELD_NAME":"UF_CRM_111111111111","USER_TYPE_ID":"enumeration","LIST":\[{"ID":"700","SORT":"10","VALUE":"text1","DEF":"N"},{"ID":"948","SORT":"20","VALUE":"text2","DEF":"N"}\]}
```

I need to output data in CSV format like this:

```
ID, ENTITY_ID, FIELD_NAME

938, CRM_DEAL, UF_CRM_111111111111, 700, text1
938, CRM_DEAL, UF_CRM_111111111111, 948, text2
```

Help me please, how can I solve this problem?

I've tried to run this code:

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd 
r = requests.get("https://myrestAPImethod")

df = pd.DataFrame(r)

print(r.text) with open("test.csv", 'w+', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f: 
f.write(r.text)
```

But I've got wrong CSV file.

I need this:

```
ID, ENTITY_ID, FIELD_NAME

938, CRM_DEAL, UF_CRM_111111111111, 700, text1
938, CRM_DEAL, UF_CRM_111111111111, 948, text2
```

But I,ve got text

```
{"ID":"938","ENTITY_ID":"CRM_DEAL","FIELD_NAME":"UF_CRM_111111111111","USER_TYPE_ID":"enumeration","LIST":\[{"ID":"700","SORT":"10","VALUE":"text1","DEF":"N"},{"ID":"948","SORT":"20","VALUE":"text2","DEF":"N"}\]}
```

in the first A1 cell (when I open CSV with Excel).

Comment: `r.text` is clearly JSON. So, what issues are you having parsing it into actual CSV data? (file extensions don't matter)

Answer (score 1):

You converted it to a dataframe with `pandas`. So now just use pandas to write to file:

```
r = {"ID":"938","ENTITY_ID":"CRM_DEAL","FIELD_NAME":"UF_CRM_111111111111","USER_TYPE_ID":"enumeration","LIST":[{"ID":"700","SORT":"10","VALUE":"text1","DEF":"N"},{"ID":"948","SORT":"20","VALUE":"text2","DEF":"N"}]}


df = pd.DataFrame(r)
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

To flatten it out a bit:

import pandas as pd

```
r = {"ID":"938","ENTITY_ID":"CRM_DEAL","FIELD_NAME":"UF_CRM_111111111111","USER_TYPE_ID":"enumeration","LIST":[{"ID":"700","SORT":"10","VALUE":"text1","DEF":"N"},{"ID":"948","SORT":"20","VALUE":"text2","DEF":"N"}]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(r).iloc[:,:-2]
df2 = pd.json_normalize(r, record_path=['LIST'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
    ID ENTITY_ID           FIELD_NAME   ID SORT  VALUE DEF
0  938  CRM_DEAL  UF_CRM_111111111111  700   10  text1   N
1  938  CRM_DEAL  UF_CRM_111111111111  948   20  text2   N
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But it works only with this construction r = {"ID":"938","ENTITY_ID":"CRM_DEAL","FIELD_NAME":"UF_CRM_111111111111","USER_TYPE_ID":"enumeration","LIST":[{"ID":"700","SORT":"10","VALUE":"text1","DEF":"N"},{"ID":"948","SORT":"20","VALUE":"text2","DEF":"N"}]}

Comment: And when I use this r = requests.get('api_url') I see TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: try:  `r = requests.get('api_url').json()`

Comment: without seeing what is actually being returned from `r = requests.get('api_url')`, I'm limited in what I can do to help

Comment: Yes, I understand. I can't share this results unfortunately(  But thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You'll have to adjust based on the json example you provided then.